# Installing OpenCV in C++ Visual Studio: How can I fix these linker errors that occur although I followed the installation tutorial?

Tags: c++, opencv, dll

I have tried downloading the C++ OpenCV Library to Visual Studio 2019.
When trying to compile my code, I am getting these errors:

```
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(40,9): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(40,19): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(42,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(42,1): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(68,62): error C2039: 'has_parenthesis_operator': is not a member of 'cv::sfinae'
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(39): message : see declaration of 'cv::sfinae'
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(68,1): error C2065: 'has_parenthesis_operator': undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(68,1): error C2977: 'std::enable_if': too many template arguments
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xtr1common(46): message : see declaration of 'std::enable_if'
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(68,117): error C2955: 'std::enable_if': use of class template requires template argument list
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xtr1common(46): message : see declaration of 'std::enable_if'
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(68,131): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(68,131): error C2059: syntax error: '>'
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(69,11): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(69,11): error C2059: syntax error: 'public'
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(69,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(69,1): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(80,26): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(140): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'cv::Ptr<T>' being compiled
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(80,35): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(80,26): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding ':'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\opencv-4.5.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp(140,1): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

I suspect it is a linker errors, so I went ahead and made sure I have included all the dependencies and libraries, and I have done as follows, I included the opencv libraries and the library directories and added the additional dependencies:
[image]
[image]

yet I am still getting the same errors. Does anyone know how I can get rid of them?
Thank you for your help!

Link to the images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obu8i.jpg

Comment: I see no errors. If you posted pictures, don't do that. Copy/paste the text. It's faster, easier for everyone, and follows the guidelines of this site.

Comment: @sweenish I am updating it right now, can you not see the images at all?

Comment: I don't even see the typical dead image boxes. It's not uncommon. Most of the people popping in *at this time of day* are at work.

Comment: @sweenish I understand,  added the errors. I suspect they are linker errors but I couldn't figure out what to change in the visual studio to make it work.

Comment: You'll have to also show how you're compiling the code. This can be an instance where images are acceptable, if you have to show a VS window. It will limit your potential audience, though. But if it's just a command or a makefile or CMakeLists.txt, that should be added as text. It looks to me like you aren't building correctly, on the CLI it's usually a missing `-lib<foo>`. I have no experience with openCV itself.

Comment: @sweenish the compilation is done via VS, which is why I included the pictures of the window, I can share an imgur link if needed so you can view it, or I can try and write the text part of the important options.

Comment: I did find this page, though. Maybe something in it will prove helpful. https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d6e/tutorial_windows_visual_studio_opencv.html

Comment: @sweenish I will try it! I'll also attach imgur links in case you or any other potential helper might find it useful!

Comment: link: https://imgur.com/a/M1UV7yL

Comment: @sweenish Update: Unfortunately the link you sent did not work, I am not sure why, it seems like it should..

Comment: That's a bummer. Hopefully someone with relevant experience pops by.

Comment: Please include your code ([\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). *BTW* those are compiler errors, the linker stage wasn't reached.

Comment: @CristiFati Hello! It was fixed in the end literally by creating a new file and copying the contents. The wonders of VS I guess :)